# What is the maximum number of characters allowed in Facebook status box?

Tags: facebook

People often update their status on Facebook, but what is the maximum number of characters allowed in Facebook status box?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<del>According to [this](http://techie-buzz.com/social-networking/facebook-has-a-420-character-status-update-limit-too.html) article, 420 characters, but I can't test it for the moment, since I don't have access to Facebook from my current network.</del>

I have just tested it and the latest iteration (late August 2011) allows for Status updates of up to 500 characters.

[image]

**UPDATE (10/11/2011):**

Facebook increased the status updates character number to 5.000. See screenshot below.

[image]

**UPDATE (30/11/2011)**

Facebook just increased the status updates character limit to 60.000.

> In September, we increased the character limit on status updates to 5,000 characters. Today, we're announcing that you can now write posts with more than 60,000 characters.

[Source](http://www.facebook.com/schrep/posts/203969696349811).

Comment: [63206 characters](http://mashable.com/2011/11/30/facebook-status-63206-characters) to be more precise.

Answer (score 3):

> Status updates must be less than 5.000 characters. You have entered 5.066 characters here. Notes can be much longer. Would you like to edit and post your update as a Note instead?

Comment: I updated my original answer. Thanks!